# Search Directory and Copy all Results to Home

Tags: file, perl

I'm looking to automate a menial process using Perl, but am not too familiar with regular expressions and such.

Let's say we're in a certain directory. I want to search for all files in that directory whose file names contain an input "string", then copy all of the results to the home directory.

How can this be done in Perl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) and [File::Copy](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html) will get you started:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Copy qw(cp);

my $str = 'foo';
for (glob "*$str*") {
    cp($_, $ENV{HOME});
}
```

Comment: actually... I'm running it now and I'm getting the following error:

Undefined subroutine &main::cp called

Comment: Ahh, okay. My bad, I didn't see that bit!

Comment: I'm just wondering, how would I rename the files after they're copied to the home directory? ie, naming each of them "${str}_0", "${str}_1", etc?